# MySQL int field resets automatically in DGNews hit counter

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

I am using a customized version of DGNews (now defunct) script in my site. In that script, there is a simple method to count the number of hits:

```
$queryfull = "SELECT * FROM news_publish WHERE id='$newsid'";
$qryfull = @mysql_query($queryfull,$connect) or die ("Wrong Query");
$rowfull = mysql_fetch_array ($qryfull);

$c=$rowfull[click];
$c++;
$d=$c;
@mysql_query("update news_publish set click='$d' where id=$newsid");
```

I know this script is using outdated mysql query methods, and I am currently not in a position to do a complete upgrade.
But my problem is, 'click' (int) field in all the rows of database, resets to 1 once in a while. I can't figureot how it happens. It happens only once in a year or so. Is this a result of some kind of attempted mysql injection or something? can somebody figureout what is going on here?

thank you

***UPDATE***
It resets the said field on ALL the rows, not in a single row

---

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because `$c=$rowfull[click];` need to be `$c=$rowfull["click"];` (quotes or double quotes around the key).

Comment: What is the maximum value of  click column you ever noticed, I think this exceed the limits of int, You can try float or double instead of using int

Comment: Why do two queries? Why not `UPDATE news_publish SET click = click + 1 where id = $newsid`?

Comment: @securedeveloper no, it never passed 20,000, the is well below the limit of int i guess...

Comment: @lolka_bolka thank you... it seems better... but would i solve the resetting issue?

Comment: @lolka_bolka yes,  in actual code, it is without double or single quotes, and it works (except this problem)

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryfull = "SELECT * FROM news_publish WHERE id='$newsid'";
$qryfull = @mysql_query($queryfull,$connect) or die ("Wrong Query");
$rowfull = mysql_fetch_array ($qryfull);

$c=$rowfull['click'];
$d=$c++;
@mysql_query("update news_publish set click='$d' where id=$newsid");
```

But you can run only update query as suggested  Barmar in comments

```
@mysql_query("update news_publish set click=click+1 where id=$newsid");
```

And thats All

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly know where the overflow is happening but this will help you.

```
alter news_publish modify click bigint
```

bigint is much much greater than int.